# Ferris Wheel Trig Problem

Tags: trigonometry, wave-equation

Your ride on a clockwise Ferris wheel begins at the top of the ride, and your height is described by the function $$h(t)=4\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{18}t\right)}+50,$$  where $h$ is in feet, and $t$ is in seconds.

Your friends are on the same ride, but they are at the “11 o’clock” position when the ride begins.  Write a function that describes THEIR height as a function of the number of seconds since the ride began.

Comment: Are you following your friend, or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it takes $2\pi/(\pi/18)=36$ seconds to complete one ride and, proportionally, $3 $ seconds between  11 and 12 o’clock.

Thus, the friends’ height function is given by

$$h_f(t)=4\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{18}(t-3)\right)}+50$$

assuming clockwise rotation.